# how to get response of http request

Tags: php, xml, google-custom-search

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am trying to get the some tag value but it's showing some error.
Below is the code, please suggest some solution.

This is the method i used for httpGet request.

```
function httpGet($result15)
{
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$result15);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

$output=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

return $output;
}



$result15= httpGet("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=API_KEY&cx=003255er&q=cancer&num=1&alt=atom");//new cse

echo $result15;
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($result15);
foreach( $xml->entry as $entry )
{
echo "URL=".(string)$entry->id.PHP_EOL;
echo "Summary=".(string)$entry->summary.PHP_EOL;

}
```

Comment: Paste this errors

Comment: I have uploaded error message screen shot, please go through it @prgj83

Comment: Your method httpGet doesnt return any value. How does this method look like?

Comment: function httpGet($result15)
{
    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$result15);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}

Comment: I have added httpGet method in the question @prgj83

Comment: check your api URL. It seems that you have wrong API KEY or other param.

Comment: I have changed the api key as it's a social site. Here i can not share the correct API key. @prgj82

Comment: I know, in edit history is still your real key and it doesn't work

Comment: It was changed at first time i posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the curl request is failing.  You need to do a couple of things...

```
function httpGet($result15)
{
    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$result15);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Add this
    $output=curl_exec($ch);
    // If this fails, output error.
    if ($output === FALSE) {
        echo curl_error($ch);
        // Not sure what you want to do, but 'exit' will work for now
        exit();
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

This will display an error if the curl request fails.  You will need to decide how your going to cope with this. You could return false, and then in your code further down, check this before trying to load it as XML.  The code above just stops on errors.

Your next piece of code seems to mix SimpleXML and DOMDocument, you can use SimpleXML if the document structure is fairly straight forward...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result15);
foreach( $xml->entry as $entry )
{
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, now i am getting this error Notice: Undefined property: DOMDocument::$entry in C:\wamp64\www\hari\cfp\www.checkforplag.com-final-new\custom-search-api-atom.php on line 46

Comment: echo  $result show: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10970142
Nonadherence to colorectal <b>cancer</b> (CRC) screening remains high among Asian <br> Americans. Screening intention among Filipino, Hmong, and Korean Americans <br> who are nonadherent is low. Knowledge of one or more screening guidelines <br> doubles the odds of intending to obtain CRC screening among these Asian <br> groups.

Comment: OK, I've added a new bit to the answer, try using SimpleXML.